# Why does this logical/bitwise operation return 1?

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic, conditional-statements

I don't understand why the following returns 1:

```
0x0102 && (0xff << 8)
```

From my understanding, bit-shifting `0xff` by eight to the left results in `0x00`; and `anding` that with anything would result in 0x00. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I see - I was getting hung up on the bitshift. It returns 0xff00, not 0x00. The logical && then returns 1.

Comment: This might help illustrate it: http://ideone.com/Xdrixx

Answer (score 3):

You are using `logical AND`, not `bitwise AND`.  Replace `&&` with `&`.

Try

```
0x0102 & (0xff << 8)
```

> From my understanding, bit-shifting 0xff by eight to the left results in 0x00; and anding that with anything would result in 0x00. Where am I wrong?

0xFF is an `int`.  Typically it is 16 or 32 bits depending on compiler settings.  So shift left by 8 bits results in `0xFF00`.

Answer (score 3):

`(0xff << 8)` results in `0xff00`. Bitwise ANDing that with `0x0102` will yield `0x0100` (which is `true`).

But, you aren't doing a bitwise AND. `&&` is logical AND. `&` is bitwise AND. What you're basically doing is `if 0x0102` is `true` AND `if (0xff << 8)` is `true`, which, since the arguments are non-zero, results in `true` (which gets converted to 1).

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is logical AND. You want bitwise AND `&`, e.g.

```
0x0102 & (0xff << 8)
```

Also, bit-shifting `0xff` by eight to the left results in `0xff00`, since bitwise arithmetic is integer rather than byte.

Answer (score 1):

An integer constant is not composed by simply 8 bits, `0xFF << 8` is `0xFF00`.

Comment: I don't why somebody did -1, so I +1 the answer.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Thanks, Maybe someone thinks I missed part of the logical X bitwise and, but I don't really think that would be the case since the answer fits perfectly in the "logical and" scenario, and I didn't find any evidence that using it is a mistake, or that it was supposed to be a "bitwise and".

Answer (score 0):

See [In C Left shift (char) 0xFF by 8 and cast it to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097130/in-c-left-shift-char-0xff-by-8-and-cast-it-to-int)

0xff << 8 yields -256. Since both sides of the AND logic gate are not 0, it will return true, or 1.