# c bit manipulation operation doesn't multiply char

Tags: c, char, bit

i have this simple code, why does it return this random char?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = '1';
     printf("%c\n",c);
    c = c << 2;

    printf("%c\n",c);

    return 0;
}



1

? (some random character)
```

why didn't it return 2?

Comment: check your answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097130/in-c-left-shift-char-0xff-by-8-and-cast-it-to-int

Answer (score 3):

Because `'1'` and `1` are not the same thing. `'1'` is a character literal that represents the number `1`, the underlying value that represents the character `'1'` depends on the charset in use.

For example, in ASCII the character `1` is represented by the decimal value 49 (hexadecimal 0x31). So assuming ASCII, `c = c << 2` assigns the value 196 (multiplies by 4) to `c`. If a `char` is signed and is 8 bits long (which is often the case) this will overflow and invoke undefined behavior.

If you want it to print `1` and `2` you should a) multiply by 2 instead of 4 (that is, shift 1 instead of 2), and b) store the numeric value instead of its representation (but of course, then you need to adjust it when printing):

```
int main()
{
    char c = 1;
    printf("%c\n", c+'0');
    c = c << 1;

    printf("%c\n", c+'0');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no standardised character set for which `'0'` through `'9'` are not consecutive.   It's a different story for letters though.

Comment: in C `'0'` to `'9'` must be consecutive http://stackoverflow.com/q/9416926/995714

Answer (score 1):

The integer `'1'` has [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value `49`. So the left shift on it, `c<<2` produces `196` which is then assigned back to `char` variable `c`. It would overflow `char` if char is `signed`. 
This is possibly what happens on your platform, printing random character.

Not sure why you expect the bit shifting to produce `2`. If you want the char `'2'` then simply add 1 to `c`.

```
c = c+1;
```

Comment: "The C standard doesn't guarantee the '1' +1 would yield '2'" - yes it does.  Section 5.2.1, (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9416926/995714 `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be contiguous be C standard

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry. I was confused it with `a` .. `z`.

Answer (score 1):

Shifting left once multiplies a value by 2. Shifting left twice multiplies a value by 4. So in the first place, you certainly won't get the answer `2` even when the code is correct.

Now to the detail. You are using the print format `%c` which shows the value as a character. The ASCII code for `'1'` is `49`. If you multiply this by 2 you get `98` which is the ASCII code for `'b'`.

You should make the adjustment for ASCII before and after the computation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c = '1';
    printf("%c\n", c);
    c = c - '0';                // ASCII adjustment
    c = c << 1;                 // double
    c = c + '0';                // ASCII adjustment
    printf("%c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: he's multiplying it by 4, not 2.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc as I explained. But he asked "why didn't it return 2?", meaning he intended to multiply by 2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to access the next character value of c. When you executed the statement `c = c << 2`

**What Actually Happened:**

- Character was first converted to integer (it's own ASCII value)
- 49 (ASCII value of `1` is `49`) is then two times multiplied by 2 (`c << 2` is basically the left shift by 2, first left shift made the original value multiplied by 2, second left shift made the result multiplied by two)
- Hence resultant value is `196` not `2` that stored in c after typecasting.

**What You Should Do:**

You should simply add `1` to the variable c, because it will convert the character to its ASCII and then will add `1` to it i.e. character `c` has the ASCII value `49`, when it will be incremented, the new value will be `50` which is equivalent to 2 when converted to character. Try this:

```
c = (int)c + 1;    //By force conversion from character to integer to get the ASCII value
```

Hope this helps.